# Can't open a connection to SQL Server 2005 from a pocketpc (windows mobile 6)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, ado.net, connection-string

I'm trying to connect from a pocket pc app (windows mobile 6) to a SQL Server 2005, but no matter how hard I try it didn't work. I checked every possible configuration for enabling tcp on SQL Server, I tested many connection strings, but still have the problem when I attempt to open the connection, I'm sure it's not a network issue because I can ping on my pocket pc from the server machine without any problem and the firewall on my server machine is disabled : here is one of the connection strings I used :

```
Data Source=10.168.0.160,1433;Initial Catalog=pos;Trusted_connection=yes;user id=myuserid;password=mypassword
```

where `pos` is the name of my database

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you cannot have both a *trusted connection* and specify an *explicit user name and password* at the same time - it's either or.

**EITHER** you connect to your server with the trusted connection, e.g. your Windows credentials - then your connection string looks something like this:

```
Data Source=10.168.0.160,1433;Initial Catalog=pos;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

**OR** alternatively, you use an explicit user name and password - but in that case, you **CANNOT** also use trusted connection / integrated security at the same time!

In this case, your connection string would be something like:

```
Data Source=10.168.0.160,1433;Initial Catalog=pos;user id=myuserid;password=mypassword
```

Check out the [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionStrings.com) for loads of samples of valid connection strings for SQL Server

Comment: sorry but i tried every possible string, it didn't worked, i always get an sqlexception with class: 14 and number 18452, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Integrated Windows Authentication from a mobile device because the device doesn't have any concept of a logged in user.  You also have to make sure the server has remote connections turned on.

[Here's a simple example of how to get it working](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/09/20/developing-connected-smart-device-application-with-sqlclient.aspx).