# connection to SQL Server 2005 from windows mobile 6

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, windows-ce, windows-mobile-6

I'm trying to connect from a pocket pc app (windows mobile 6) to a SQL Server 2005, but no matter how hard I try it didn't work. I checked every possible configuration for enabling tcp on SQL Server, I tested many connection strings, but still have the problem when I attempt to open the connection, I'm sure it's not a network issue because I can ping on my pocket pc from the server machine without any problem and the firewall on my server machine is disabled : here is one of the connection strings I used :

```
Data Source=10.168.0.160,1433;Initial Catalog=pos;Trusted_connection=yes;user id=domain\myuserid;password=mypassword
```

where pos is the name of my database

I keep getting a SqlException with class 14 and number 18452, and I can't figure this out

Thank you for your help

Comment: Duplicate of [Can't open a connection to SQL Server 2005 from a pocketpc (windows mobile 6)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042484/cant-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-2005-from-a-pocketpc-windows-mobile-6)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to use Integrated Windows Authentication while at the same time specifying the Windows credentials to use. This is not how IWA works. IWA uses the currently logged in user's credentials. In your connection string, specifying the user ID and password doesn't achieve anything.

If you were to remove

```
Trusted_Connection=yes;
```

then you would be using SQL Server Authentication, but you'd have to ensure that a user exists in SQL Server with the correct credentials.

Comment: i tried a lot of connection string, among them what you juste said, but i can't understand how to connect using a domain user, and how to create a domain user at sql server

Comment: @Tarik - As far as I am aware, you *can't* specify a Windows user in a connection string - just the currently logged on user is used. Therefore, you either have to ensure you're logged in on the device as a Windows user that has access to the database, or use SQL Authentication instead.

Comment: Seems that nothing wants to work, perhaps if somebody knows a good tuto for accessing sqlserver from pocket pc i will be grateful